# No executable model found for artifact <G:A:V>. Falling back to resources parsing

Tags: jbpm, rhpam

I've linked a Business Rule Task in one kjar (holds the bpmn files) to the DRL file in another kjar to account for the distinct cadence of Processes vs rules as advised by Maciec in the KIE Blog [CONTROL BUSINESS RULES EXECUTION FROM YOUR PROCESSES](https://blog.kie.org/2017/04/control-business-rules-execution-from-your-processes.html).

Both the DRL and BPMN are housed under the same path (package name).
I can execute the DRL if it is in the same KJar (using the RuleFlowGroup value).

But when I try linking calls across the two kjars using the WorkItemHandler:
BusinessRuleTask  :  new org.jbpm.process.workitem.bpmn2.BusinessRuleTaskHandler("", "", "")

I see

```
INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModuleProvider] (default task-133) Creating KieModule for artifact <G>:<A...>kjar-rules:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
INFO  [org.drools.modelcompiler.CanonicalKieModuleProvider] (default task-133) No executable model found for artifact <G>:<A...>kjar-rules:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. Falling back to resources parsing.
INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModuleProvider] (default task-133) Creating KieModule for artifact <G>:<A...>model:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
INFO  [org.drools.modelcompiler.CanonicalKieModuleProvider] (default task-133) No executable model found for artifact <G>:<A...>model:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. Falling back to resources parsing.
INFO  [stdout] (default task-133)
INFO  [stdout] (default task-133) ----------- entering biz rules task.... (entry script)
INFO  [stdout] (default task-133)
INFO  [stdout] (default task-133)      --- missing execution trigger for DRL ....
INFO  [stdout] (default task-133) ... exiting biz rules task  (exit script)
```

Any thoughts on what the issue could be here?